# Can a Service Layer contain multiple services?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, service-layer

I'm rearchitecting a large web forms ASP.Net application, inserting a service layer to take away unwanted responsibility from the presentation layer.

I've seen a lot of examples where all the service methods are contained in one class.

Is this common / best practice? Or is it perfectly feasible to have a number of service classes within the service layer? I'm leaning towards having more than one service and those services being able to talk to each other.

Any guidance, pros/cons?

Richard

P.s. Note that I'm not talking about a *web* service layer, WCF or otherwsie, although that might become more relevant at a later date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), specifically the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) would suggest that having all of your functionality in one object is a bad idea, and i tend to agree.  As your application grows the single class will become difficult to maintain.

Your comments to Yuriys answer would suggest you want to use an IOC container.  Lets consider that in more detail for a moment...

The more functionality this single class contains, the more dependencies it will require.  You could well end up having a constructor on the service that has a long list of parameters, simply because the class covers a lot of ground and depends on other functionality at a lower level, such as logging, database communication, authentication etc.  Lets say a consumer of that service wants to call one, and only one specific method on that class before destroying the instance.  Your IOC container will need to inject every dependency that the service could 'possibly' need at runtime, even though the consumer will only use maybe 1 or 2 of those dependencies.

Also from an operational perspective - if you have more than one developer on the team working on the service layer at the same time, there is more possibility of merge conflicts if you are both editing one file.  But, as suggested you could use partials to counter that issue.

Usually a dose of practicality alongside a well known pattern or principle is the best way forward.

I would suggest researching [Service Orientated Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) if you havent already, as it may help you answer some key decisions in the approach to your solution.

Comment: That's a great answer and confirms what my gut feeling was telling me.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it can. 
Moreover, I believe that would be better to extract from this God service layer class few interfaces by functionality (i.e. ISecurityService, INotificationService etc.) and implement each interface in separate project. Also, you can utilize some IOC container to resolve class that implement service's interface. This way you can change each service's implementation independently without changing client functionality.

At least, for the first time you can mark your service super class as partial, then split it up by functionality into few .cs(.vb) files with meaningful names and group them together in Visual Studio. This will simplify navigating across service methods.

Comment: I'm wary of having seperate projects as the app is big and so is the service layer surface. I can see why having security in a different service project would be handy for reuse though. Agree on the IoC front as the benefits that brings is where I want to go. For now - hopefully someone else also has an opinion - I'll break it into several service classes.

Answer (score 0):

My take on structuring an application would be to start with splitting the application into two projects AppX.Web (UI logic) and AppX.Business (business logic), but still keep them in the same VS solution. The clarify in structure between business logic and UI logic helps you understand what services are shared among multiple web pages and which are local to a singel web page. You should avoid reusing code directly between the web pages, if you find that this is necessary then you should probaly move that piece of shared code to the business logic layer.

When implementing the business logic project you should try to create separate classes for different type of business logic. These classes can of course talk to eachother, but do avoid having the web pages talk to eachother.

Once you have separated UI logic from business logic you can continue to break down the AppX.Business code into smaller pieces if necessary. Common examples include:

- AppX.Data: A Data Access Layer (DAL) which isolate all data manipulation from the actual business logic
- AppX.Dto: Data Transfer Objects (DTO) which can be useful in many scenarios, e.g. when sending data to the client browser for processing by jQuery
- AppX.Common: Shared logic which is generic to many other applications, this can be helper classes you have previously created or things which should be reviewed after the project for inclusion in company wide support classes.

Finally, let's talk about going all-in and expose your business logic as a WCF service. In that case you actually need not change anything in the existing structure. You can either add the WCF service to your existing AppX.Web project or expose them separately in AppX.Service. If you have properly separated business logic from UI logic the WCF layer can be just a thin wrapper around the business logic.

When implementing the WCF service it is quite possible to do all of that in a single class. No real business logic is available in the WCF service as it just make direct calls to the business logic.

If you build a new application you should consider you overall design up front, but now that you are rearchitecting I think you should work step-by-step:

- Start by creating the AppX.Web and AppX.Business Projects
- Identify services and create classes in AppX.Business for those services
- Move code from the AppX.Web project into the new classes in AppX.Business, and make sure you call them from the web project.
- Continue with additional break-down if you feel you need to do so!

Comment: Hi, the project is fully split. I was wondering on best practice for service layers as prior to that it was just unit of work on a facade in the client and that was becoming inwieldy in larger apps.